# Youtube Webservices in different Android devices

Tags: android, video-streaming, youtube-api

To fetch the video's list from YouTube, I am using this web service:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=flowers
```

I am getting different list of video's. My problem is am getting three different video URL's for every video. Which one should i use for which devices ?

How to support multiple resolutions and multiple player formats like Flash player and normal player for playing 3gp/mp4/rtsp.

I got some information from the Google Youtube API

The Video URL codes defines the formats below

1 - Mobile Videos (H.263)
5 - Embeddable player
6 - Mobile Videos    (MPEG-4 SP)

But how do you check which device is suitable for a given video type ?

Comment: So you are working with Android, correct? [see this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: This just gives me an idea of different video types support but nothing more useful.

Comment: Some how the below Sample project helped me to fox this issue. [http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/source/checkout](http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/source/checkout)